# How to use slash to access base directory in JAVA?

Tags: java, maven-3

I have created a maven project and in that project one properties file. Now to access that properties file I have to put entire path of that file. How can I use slash to access the base directory, so that I just need to write:

```
properties.load(new FileReader("/testdata.properties"));<br>
```

instead of

```
properties.load(new FileReader("C:/Users/windows7/workspace/project/package/testdata.properties"));
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest taking a look at [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) home or class path resource instead of using slash?

Comment: It's safe to always use / in paths like that.  java handles it just fine.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Mainly I meant it as a habit. And as a beginner using slashes can get confusing.

Comment: @Atul, I went to that link, its good to know but doesnt solve my query.What if I want to load Chrome Binary from my resources directory, there I will provide entire path, but I just want to use slash to reach my home directory (project dir).

Comment: @paul the resources relative to classpath can be loaded and read based on the classpath. You can have a look at Jon's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1464366/668951

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` will help you to navigate to the path of your directory. You can append to that path to reach to your file location.

Comment: This is not the question, what if I want to load Chrome Binary from my resources directory, there I will provide entire path, but I just want to use slash to reach my home directory (project dir). UpVote for this answer is not right, please downvote as I dont have privileges to do so.